# VBA Autofilter when result is nothing ERROR in the code

Tags: vba, autofilter

I have the below code and I get an error when trying to run it "No cell were found".

This is because after filtering sometimes I have no result.

```
Worksheets("DATA").Activate
Worksheets("DATA").AutoFilterMode = False
If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If


Selection.AutoFilter Field:=95, Criteria1:=Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), Operator:=xlFilterValues


ActiveSheet.Range("2:" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Selection.AutoFilter
```

I would like to have a code that tells to ignore the code if the Autofilter returns no result.

Any idea how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `Activesheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count` to get the number of Rows visible after filtering. And put it in a if condition.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
Worksheets("DATA").Activate
Worksheets("DATA").AutoFilterMode = False
If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If


Selection.AutoFilter Field:=95, Criteria1:=Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then

ActiveSheet.Range("2:" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Selection.AutoFilter

End If
```

Comment: I might be wrong but... If headers are on row 2 this won't work.

Comment: @Damian ... You are right... But in the code if you see the range that is being deleted starts from 2nd Row. So I assumed that the headers are in 1st row only.

Answer (score 0):

You can just ignore the error :

```
Worksheets("DATA").Activate
Worksheets("DATA").AutoFilterMode = False
If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=95, Criteria1:=Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("2:" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Selection.AutoFilter

On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions work. I am getting the below error:
Run-time error '1004': Autofilter method of Range class failed

Comment: Try to write `On Error Resume Next` before the line that produces the error.